Are x-means' BIC and likelihood scores comparable between clusters of different dimensionality?
I'm currently working on implementing an x-means variant and ran into an issue when computing the Bayesian Information Criterion's log-likelihood (via scipy's multivariate normal logpdf) which fails on a lower-space clusters.
The use case is the k-means-like clustering of geographic points via their 3D Cartesian coords, but with configurable max k clusters. The coordinate system has (0,0,0) as the Earth's center, and the points are all ~6371 units away. Therefore, the clusters can be flat, very curved, or even somewhat 1D-like, but never a proper 3D Gaussian. Hence the current plan is to attempt dimensionality reduction via PCA on subclusters while computing the BIC score.
The question is: Will the BIC and log-likelihood score mostly comparable between clusters of different dimensions when using this implementation, presumably based on Ishioka's (2000) extension? Note that this implementation computes BIC on single clusters, then performs some sort of merged BIC on the 2 new clusters via their individually cached covariance/likelihood/BIC.
And, if not, what may be other options for max k clustering (alternate likelihood functions, clustering algorithms, etc)?
